# TextBlock in c# get an empty value in RowEditEnding in datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I use RowEditEnding event in datagrid to get updated row and update my database in return

```
    private void OnUpdateOrInsertItem(object sender,DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;

        int row_index = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row1);
        int numberOfColumns = ((DataGrid)sender).Columns.Count;
        DataGridCell RowColumn = ((DataGrid)sender).Columns[1].GetCellContent(row1).Parent as DataGridCell;
        string CellValue = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
        MessageBox.Show(CellValue);
    }
```

but when I change cell which I print it in messageBox ,it returns an empty value on messageBox.
I think the problem related to threads 
this is my xml code

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="248" Width="672"  RowEditEnding="OnUpdateOrInsertItem" PreviewKeyDown="OnDeleteItem"/>
    <Button Content="Show Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.193,-13.506" Height="29" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="469,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

how can I solve this problem or if there another way to get updated row in RowEditEnding event ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (and [templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), here done automatically by the data grid). The updated value will then be in your bound (view) model without any need for using that event.
2. Don't use `ItemContainerGenerator`. If you need access to the UI items, then bind the relevant properties to your underlying view model.